# Is it a good practice and can it improve the performance when we use the Model directly in the view, following MVC stucture, PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, yii2

I am working with Yii framework 2.0. But this question is for MVC in general. I understand how MVC works, but I am wondering whether it is a good practice and can it improve the performance of a website when we use a Model directly inside a view without passing it through a controller. Below is my sample code:

```
class MyModel {
     public static function doAction() {
         // do something here...
     }

     public function getPizza() {
         // return pizza ..
     }
}
```

Inside my sample_view1.php:

```
<?php MyModel::doAction(); ?>
```

Inside my sample_view2.php:

```
<?php
     $myModel = new MyModel();
     echo $myModel->getPizza();
?>
```

To me, I think it might improve the performance because the controller does not need to process the model and pass it to the view. But I am not sure about that. I have red some article related to this. But each has his own opinion. Hope some senior PHP developers can give me some advice to improve me.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment about defined roles of components, when model contains logic, view contains presentation and controller manage how it works together. And this is what a programmer familiar with MVC pattern keeps in mind. He expects the things will be there where they should be.

In your example `<?php MyModel::doAction(); ?>` it looks like `doAction()` is responsive for displaying some data. Finding it in a view is a little bit unexpected and confusing. One of ways when you can use constructions like `<?php MyModel::doAction(); ?>` its when you build a dropdown list or list of radio inputs e.g.

`<?= Html::dropDownList( MyModel::getSomeList() ) ?>`

About instantiating model class in a view and get some data to display:

```
<?php
     $myModel = new MyModel();
     echo $myModel->getPizza();
?>
```

Its just and example, but what if you need more method calls before you can call `getPizza()` ? e.g.

```
<?php
     $myModel = new MyModel();
     $myModel->prepare();
     $myModel->check();
     //and so on...
     //and finally
     echo $myModel->getPizza();
?>
```

View becomes messy. And look at this snippet: `<?= $pizza ?>` when you just pass `$pizza` as parameter to view from controller. It looks nice and clean.
 So why make things less readable ?

Answer (score 1):

MVC its not about perfomance. its about architecture. some kind of methodology.
In your case improvement of perfomance will be scanty.

If you think in other way - you should forget about OOP and think about procedural.

My advice will be not to use models in views directly.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about the performance. Can you give me a disadvantage why it is not a good practice to use models in views directly? Not that I want to use models in views directly all the time. but in some case models do not need to be processed by controllers before passing it to the views. As you could see in my sample code above, we could skip the controller. So why not?

Comment: The benefit of an architectural style is that is provides defined roles for different components of your application. There is a lot of debate on where the actual work is done in the "MVC" architecture on the web, should it be done in the controller or in the model (the right answer is the model) but I think everyone agrees that the role of the view layer should be only presentation.